# CoreData: Managed Objects in other Managed Objects are null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

so I have a problem: Let's say I have Messages and Users and the information for them is stored in CoreData. There is a relation so you can code something like `aMessage.SentBy.FirstName`. In a table view I want to show Message titles and User's full name. So I get the result, reload the table and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. What happens is if I have 3 messages from one user, only one of them would return the FirstName, the others would return "(null)"!!!

Why is that happening? Maybe I am doing something wrong :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your relationship from Users -> Messages is to-one. Whenever you set the SentBy relation on a Message, it overwrites the previous Message relationship on the user.

You need to make it a to-many relationship.

On your object graph, it should look like this:

User <------>> Message